# Mark task as "Today" from project screen?

Tags: asana

When in the "New Tasks" view, there is a shortcut that allows you to prioritize tasks as "Today", "Upcoming", or "Later":

[image: New Tasks shortcut]

However, I often find myself reviewing tasks in a *project*, and realizing that some task should be done "Today".  I cannot find any way to do this, without returning to "My Tasks" and searching anew for the task there.

Is there a shortcut I'm missing?

If not, where is the best place to vote on feature requests like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the task selected (highlighted in the left pane, and open on the right), you can use the keyboard shortcuts `Tab+Y`, `Tab+U`, and `Tab+L` to mark tasks assigned to you as Today, Upcoming, and Later, respectively.

https://asana.com/guide/help/faq/shortcuts

Comment: Well, now I am no longer a rudderless asana user.